# Rest API not returning results after adding security filter

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a POST Rest endpoint which returns a list of Strings upon successful execution. Recently i attempted to secure it using Spring Security. Nothing crazy, i attempted simple implementation which checks if Bearer token provided is not null.

This is my SecurityConfig class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/home").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint).and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

       httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

}

This is my JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint class:

```
@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint, 
Serializable {

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                     AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException {
        String token = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (token == null) {
          response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Unauthorized");
        }
    }
}
```

And below is my Filter class:

```
@Component
public class JwtRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
                   response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

When i access the Rest API(through postman) providing a null token, it returns 401 UnAuthorized as expected. But when i access it by providing a valid Bearer token(not providing it here for security reasons), it returns 200 ok http status, but the response is null in the postman body(expected response is list of strings). What i am thinking is that the control is not going back to the Rest Controller API after the filter(httpSecurity.addFilterBefore) is processed in SecurityConfig. Is there a way to fix this? I changed POST to GET and i still see the problem.

Comment: Look at your filter. Look at the location of the `chain` call.

Comment: @tgdavies i put chain call at the right place and i still see the same issue

Answer (score 0):

In the *doFilterInternal* method of ***JwtRequestFilter*** class, the call to  `chain.doFilter(request, response)` should be in the if condition.

```
if (requestTokenHeader != null && requestTokenHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
        jwtToken = requestTokenHeader.substring(7);
        Logger.info("Token Value: " + jwtToken);
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
```

The else block should contain the logic for the invalid token.

```
 else {
        Logger.warn("Invalid Token");
        // code to send invalid token message to the user
 }
```